# ReactNative run out of scope animations in parallel

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

In order to run sequance of animations in parallel ReactNative Animated API provides `Animated.parallel` method.

This approach works just fine considering that all the animations objects are in the scope of the animated component.

However sometimes one might want to incapsulate repeatable animation logic into different component such as `<Fade/>`.

What is considered to be a desirable approach for the case when we build a component that reuses many subcomponents that incapsulate each corresponding animation to run it at the same time in parallel ?